# Determine who has read a mail in shared mailbox

Tags: vb.net, vba, email, outlook, collaboration

I'm thinking about a possibility to determine **who** has read a mail in a shared mailbox at Outlook 2010.

Of course a MailItem doesn't hold a property like "readBy", that's why I'm looking for a way to respond to the fact **that** a message has been marked as read. Then I could write the current user name to a userdefined field.

**My first idea:**

Listen to `MailItem.Read()` or `MailItem.Open()` with a VBA macro, but - when I'm not wrong - `MailItem.Open()` is thrown when a MailItem is *focused* and shown in the reading pane. If Outlook doesn't mark it as read automatically, the Info "Read by Max" would be wrong. 
`MailItem.Read()` is thrown only when a MailItem is opened to a new window, but what's when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>?

After some Googling it seems that VBA isn't able to solve this on a good way or is it?
Should I think about writing an Add-In?

Do you have any idea how I could go about this? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a bad idea - now you need to **modify** the message when all a user did was read it. And that will automatically update the last modified time/name/entry id.

Keep in mind that read/unread status is technically not a part of message, hence resetting it does not modify the message. More than that, the PF store stores the read/unread state on the per-user basis.

Comment: Isn't there a bool MailItem.UnRead as a part of the message? Why is the last modified time etc. relevant?

Comment: I'd say, the only thing I'm searching for is to be nodified, when **I** read a mail over my Outlook and **not** be notified, when another Mailbox user reads a mail.

Comment: Yes, Unread is part of the MailItem object in the Outlook Object Model, but on the store level, the property is stored separately form other message properties (such as the Subject). Modifying that property does not reset the modified date.

Comment: You can use the Items.ItemChange event on that folder - it gets called when an item is modified or if its unread status changes. But you will not know who exactly caused the item to become read.

Comment: hm ok. Any Idea how i could achieve it? A possibility to add custom actions before Outlook marks a Mail as read? Otherwise i have to accept that this is impossible.

Comment: You can use MailItem.PropertyChange event - it will fire for the Unread property only on the machine where the change it being made. To subscribe to the event on all items that the current user can modify, you will need to listen to the Explorer.SelectionChange event and the Inspectors.NewInspector events.

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model provides the [PropertyChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868239(v=office.15).aspx) event which is fired when an explicit built-in property (for example, Subject) of an instance of the parent object is changed.

Also the [ItemChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865866(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Items class is fired when an item in the specified collection is changed. You can check the Read property of the Outlook item passed as a parameter.

In case if you need to handle the item-level events you may find the [Developing an Inspector Wrapper for Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973716(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. Maybe that's a stupid question but the thing where I am unsure is, are these events fired only when **I** change a property or also when another colleague changes the property?

Comment: The event will fire in both cases. You won't know who caused the change.

Comment: The change will be made for all users, so when anybody changes an Outlook item you will get the events fired.